# How to insert the same record into two different table in java?

Tags: java, mysql, database, jtable

How can I insert records into two different table? I made two sql statement and it won't work.

```
private void cmdsubmitActionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt) {                                          
        // TODO add your handling code here:
        try {
            String sql = "Insert into customer (Customer_ID,First_Name,Last_Name,Birthdate,Gender,Occupation,Address,Email,Contact,Status,Income,Amount,Term,Interest,Date_Applied,Purpose,Other) values (?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?)";
            pst = conn.prepareStatement(sql);
            pst.setString(1, txtID.getText());
            pst.setString(2, txtfname.getText());
            pst.setString(3, txtlname.getText());
            pst.setString(4,((JTextField)birthdate.getDateEditor().getUiComponent()).getText());
            String gender = cmbgender.getSelectedItem().toString();
            pst.setString(5, gender);
            pst.setString(6, txtoccupation.getText());
            pst.setString(7, txtaddress.getText());
            pst.setString(8, txtemailadd.getText());
            pst.setString(9, txtcontact.getText());
            String status = cmbstatus.getSelectedItem().toString();
            pst.setString(10, status);
            String income = cmbincome.getSelectedItem().toString();
            pst.setString(11,income);
            pst.setString(12, txtamount.getText());
            String period = cmbperiod.getSelectedItem().toString();
            pst.setString(13, txtloan.getText() + " " + period);
            pst.setString(14, txtinterest.getText());
            pst.setString(15, ((JTextField)datechooser.getDateEditor().getUiComponent()).getText());
            String purpose = cmbpurpose.getSelectedItem().toString();
            pst.setString(16, purpose);
            pst.setString(17, txtother.getText());

            Double balance = Double.parseDouble(txtamount.getText()) * Double.parseDouble(txtinterest.getText());
            String s = "Insert into payments (Customer_ID,Customer_Name,Amount,Interest,To_Pay) values (?,?,?,?,?)";
            pst = conn.prepareStatement(s);
            pst.setString(1, txtID.getText());
            pst.setString(2, txtfname.getText()+","+txtlname.getText());
            pst.setString(3, txtamount.getText());
            pst.setString(4, txtinterest.getText());
            pst.setString(5, balance.toString());

            pst.execute();
            JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "Record Save");

            Menu menu = new Menu();
            this.setVisible(false);
            menu.setVisible(true);


        }
        catch (Exception e) {
            JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, e);
        }
    }
```

Comment: You are only executing once, need another pst.execute()

Answer (score 1):

The problem appears to be that you aren't calling `pst.execute()` before you call this line:
   `pst = conn.prepareStatement(s);`

This is overwriting your previous `pst` variable; creating a new `PreparedStatement`.

Comment: @AldrinBerana You're welcome!  If this solved the issue, I'd recommend marking the Accept button (the checkmark beneath the vote counter)

Answer (score 1):

I'm not entirely sure about that API, but it seems like you have one execute for two statements. Also, you should consider making a function if a good chunk of the code is exactly the same. Less places to maintain